# Case of mandatory decltype in C++ lambda functions

Tags: c++, xtensor

There is a tensor algebra library called **xtensor**.
It has special semantics: when you form an expression (like `a * b + c`) of multiple variables you usually `std::move` or `std::forward` them into that expression. When you use a variable multiple times in the expression one of the good ways of doing this (as stated in official  documentation) would be to create additional lambda function which takes that variable and uses it multiple times inside. Obviously you cannot simply write `sin(std::move(A)) + cos(std::move(A))`. You have to write something like this:

```
template <class E>
inline auto sin_plus_cos(E&& e) noexcept
{
    auto func = [](auto x) -> decltype(sin(x) + cos(x)) {
        return sin(x) + cos(x);
    };
    return detail::make_lambda_function(std::move(func), std::forward<E>(e));
}
```

The issue is that this code works without `decltype`.

In **xtensor**'s code you can find the comment:

> `auto` lambda functions are automatically vectorized with `xsimd` if possible (note that the trailing `-> decltype(...)` is mandatory for the feature detection to work).

My question is: why it may be necessary to use `decltype` in such a way that automatic deduction of return type is not enough (or enough but not particularly efficient)?

I don't get why `decltype` have to be used in that case.
I don't want to write same expression 2 times in every such function. (And what to do with `decltype` if I have multiple lines of code with temporary variables)

Comment: No, it is not necessary, in modern C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavxhik How "modern"? Inquiring minds want to know.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It would be good to understand if this is any of the standards. In my experience I have had to do this in similar situations in as modern as C++14 because the compiler got confused. Was this changes in C++17 or C++20?

Comment: Personally I find this a very good question, and very well formulated. It may get a bit more attention with a title along the lines of: "Why do I need decltype to help to the deduces the type of auto returns?" (Because in fact I don't think your question is specific to xtensor, it's just an illustration here)

Comment: A significant difference between lambda with decltype return and without is that the return type is required if you want it to be sfinae-friendly. Is it possible the feature detection uses sfinae and the comment is just warning about that.